# Creating relationships between Neo4j nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have nodes with two labels: Country and Continent.

Each country has a property called continent_code and I want to create a relationship between all the countries and their corresponding continent.

What I could achieve is only to create the relationships for a given continent like this:

```
MATCH (u:Country {continent_code:"NORAM"}), (a:Continent {code:"NORAM"})
MERGE (u)-[r:IS_COUNTRY_OF]->(a)
RETURN u, a, r
```

Now what I would like to do is something more like this:

```
MATCH (u:Country {continent_code: a:Continent.code})
MERGE (u)-[r:IS_COUNTRY_OF]->(a)
RETURN u, a, r
```

Obviously this is not working, but I have no idea how to fix it, I am not even sure if it is possible in Neo4j/cypher.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple combine `MATCH` and `MERGE`:

```
MATCH (u:Country) WHERE LENGTH(u.continent_code)>0
MERGE (a:Continent {code: u.continent_code})
MERGE (u)-[r:IS_COUNTRY_OF]->(a)
RETURN u,r,a
```

Comment: Thank you, this exactly does what I wanted.

Comment: Although this query should work, it invokes `MERGE` for the same continent multiple times (once for each country in that continent).

Comment: @cybersam Yes, you are right, but how many of the countries and continents of the world? :)

Answer (score 3):

This might be what you want:

```
MATCH (u:Country)
WITH u.continent_code AS cc, COLLECT(u) AS countries
MERGE (a:Continent { code: cc })
FOREACH (c IN countries | MERGE (c)-[r:IS_COUNTRY_OF]->(a))
RETURN cc, countries;
```

It aggregates all the countries with the same continent code, uses `MERGE` to make sure the required `Continent` nodes exist, does a `MERGE` on each `Country` to make sure it has a relationship to its `Continent`, and returns each continent code with a collection of its countries.

Comment: Thank you, this does what I wanted. In the end I I decided to accept the other answer, because to me it seems simpler. But still thanks a lot, it would be nice to be able to accept two answers.

Comment: My answer only invokes `MERGE` once per continent. So, it should be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple search for the country and continent and creation of the relationship would work if I correctly understand your question.  Your property(continent_code) on the Country node is not really needed with the relationship(IS_COUNTRY_OF) created between the Country and the Continent nodes.

```
MATCH (ctry:Country),(cont:Continent)
WHERE ctry.name = 'Some Country Name' AND cont.name = 'Some Cont Name'
CREATE (ctry)-[r:IS_COUNTRY_OF]->(cont)
RETURN ctry, r, cont
```